# A statement about the $\arctan$ function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

While we are studying the $\arctan$ function I found this exercise:

> Is this statement true ? 
>   $$(\forall n\in \mathbb{N})  (\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R^+}) : n\arctan(\alpha)= \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arctan(\frac{k}{n}).$$

I tried to simplify the sum but It didn't work . Please don't tell me the answer just give me a hint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Since the function  $\arctan$ is increasing then
$$\arctan(0)\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \arctan(k/n)\leq \arctan(1).$$
Note that  $\arctan$ is continuous on the real line.

Comment: Thanks I did it .I found ($ \forall n \in \mathbb{N^*}) :$ $\frac{1}{n} \le \alpha \le 1$